# How do I use SharedPreferences with Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-sharedpreferences

Currently this is how my FB login looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    TAG = "Login.Activity";

    //Callback manager manages callbacks into the FB SDK from an Activity's onActivityResult() Method.
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        //If login in successful,
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            goMainScreen(profile);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.cancel_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
private void goMainScreen(Profile profile) {
    if(profile != null){
        //Passing in the name,id and photo from the profile.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       // intent.putExtra("name",profile.getName());
        intent.putExtra("id",profile.getId());
        intent.putExtra("photo",profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
//All Request Code, Result Code, and data are recieved by the activity
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
}
}
```

I would like to keep track of the user session throughout other activities and know if they have logged in before.Would I use sharedpreferences for this? If so will I be doing this at the beginning of the loginActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use what provide the SDK and create a method like this one :

```
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    return accessToken != null;
}
```

Comment: So will this be in the onCreate method in every activity?

Comment: Call this method whenever you want to check if a user is logged via facebook

Comment: Do you think I will not have to use shared preferences then?

Comment: yep as Facebook sdk permit you to check if a session exists

Comment: So the accesstoken is a way of checking if the session exist?Could you elabroate on this for me please?

Comment: this might help you [AccessToken Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

Comment: Also [AccessToken details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/#getCurrentAccessToken)

Comment: Thank you for your help.Although I did not use the code you provided. It helped me understand the process.